# sql fetching data in minutes not getting proper result

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a transaction Table like this:

```
Tbarcode     PlateNo     DelDate                    status
10           101        2014-03-26 12:14:10.000       4
11           102        2014-03-26 12:10:10.000       4
12           103        2014-03-26 12:05:10.000       5
13           104        2014-03-26 12:15:10.000       5
```

i want to get all records status 4 and status 5(but status 5 only need DelDate+3 minute of the current time).if current time is exceed more than 3 minute of deldate,i dont want to show status 5 records..i wrote something like this:

```
select t.TBarcode,t.PlateNo   from transaction_tbl t  where status in(4,5) and DATEDIFF(n,CAST(DelDate as datetime),GETDATE())<=3
```

but this is not working ..how i can do this? any help is very appricaibale

Comment: Not working as in how? Error message? Wrong result?

Comment: getting wrong  Result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you just need to use an OR instead of 'IN' to handle your WHERE.

Something like:

```
SELECT  t.TBarcode ,
        t.PlateNo
FROM    transaction_tbl t
WHERE   [status] = 4
       OR ([status] = 5 AND DATEDIFF(n, CAST(DelDate AS DATETIME), GETDATE()) <= 3)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
SELECT  t.TBarcode ,
        t.PlateNo
FROM    transaction_tbl t
WHERE   status = 4
UNION
SELECT  t.TBarcode ,
        t.PlateNo
FROM    transaction_tbl t
WHERE   status = 5
        AND DATEDIFF(n, CAST(DelDate AS DATETIME), GETDATE()) <= 3
```